# D3 force link not connected with nodes after update position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm very new to d3.js library.

In click function that have list variable that contain new position of each node,
after click on some node i want all nodes move to the new position that specified in list variable and it work properly but edges did not connected with nodes anymore.

so how can i fix that.

```js
var w = 550;
var h = 550;
var ptop = 70;
var pright = 250;

var dataset = {
    nodes:  [
            {name:"Adam", x:180, y:200, fixed:true},
            {name:"Bob",x:100, y:210, fixed:true},
            {name:"Carrie", x:300, y:150, fixed:true},
            {name:"Donovan", x:250, y:300, fixed:true},

    ],
    edges:[
            {source: 0, target: 1},
            {source: 0, target: 2},
            {source: 0, target: 3},
    ]
};
var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(dataset.nodes)
            .links(dataset.edges)
            .size([w, h])
            .linkDistance([100])
            .charge([-150])
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();


var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("top", (ptop)+"px")
                .style("right", (pright)+"px")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);


var edges = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(dataset.edges)
                .enter().append("line")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-opacity", .2)
                .style("stroke-width", 1);


var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 6)
                .style("fill", function(d, i){return colors(i); })
                .on("click", click);

        
    function tick(){
        nodes
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")"; });
        edges
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        
    }

function click(d){ 
    update_position = [
            {name:"Adam", x:300, y:100, fixed:true},
            {name:"Bob",x:180, y:200, fixed:true},
            {name:"Carrie", x:100, y:100, fixed:true},
            {name:"Donovan", x:120, y:300, fixed:true},
    ],

    nodes.data(update_position)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v3 of `d3.layout.force()` the force function mutates the edges to include the x and y coordinates when it is called `tick`. Therefore, in order to correct this, you need to get the edges again and call the force on tick method again and then draw the nodes and edges. So your click function should be like:

```
function click(d) {
  var update_position = [
        {
        name: "Adam",
        x: 300,
        y: 100,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Bob",
        x: 180,
        y: 200,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Carrie",
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Donovan",
        x: 120,
        y: 300,
        fixed: true
      },
    ];

// Map the edges again to the indexes
  var newedges = dataset.edges.map(m => {
        m.source = update_position.findIndex(f => f.name == m.source.name)
      m.target = update_position.findIndex(f => f.name == m.target.name);
      return m;
    })

  //recalculate the nodes and edges
  force.nodes(update_position)
        .links(newedges)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

  nodes.data(update_position);
  edges.data(newedges);

}
```

Full Snippet:

```js
var w = 550;
var h = 550;
var ptop = 70;
var pright = 250;

var dataset = {
  nodes: [{
      name: "Adam",
      x: 180,
      y: 200,
      fixed: true
    },
    {
      name: "Bob",
      x: 100,
      y: 210,
      fixed: true
    },
    {
      name: "Carrie",
      x: 300,
      y: 150,
      fixed: true
    },
    {
      name: "Donovan",
      x: 250,
      y: 300,
      fixed: true
    },

  ],
  edges: [{
      source: 0,
      target: 1
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 2
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 3
    },
  ]
};

const edgesST = [{
      source: 0,
      target: 1
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 2
    },
    {
      source: 0,
      target: 3
    },
  ]

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(dataset.nodes)
  .links(dataset.edges)
  .size([w, h])
  .linkDistance([100])
  .charge([-150])
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();


var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("top", (ptop) + "px")
  .style("right", (pright) + "px")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


var edges = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(dataset.edges)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
  .style("stroke-width", 1);


var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors(i);
  })
  .on("click", click);


function tick() {
  nodes
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")";
    });
  edges
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

}

function click(d) {
  var update_position = [
    {
        name: "Adam",
        x: 300,
        y: 100,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Bob",
        x: 180,
        y: 200,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Carrie",
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        fixed: true
      },
      {
        name: "Donovan",
        x: 120,
        y: 300,
        fixed: true
      },
    ];
    
// Map the edges again to the indexes
  var newedges = dataset.edges.map(m => {
     m.source = update_position.findIndex(f => f.name == m.source.name)
      m.target = update_position.findIndex(f => f.name == m.target.name);
      return m;
    })
    
  //recalculate the nodes and edges
  force.nodes(update_position)
        .links(newedges)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
  
  nodes.data(update_position);
  edges.data(newedges);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```